# How to avoid fake directory as current path when using mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite and here is the full contents of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ index.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+\.html)$ index.php?post=$1 [L]
```

It works but I have a problem. When I request **/tag/sometag** it gets translated to **/index.php?tag=sometag**, as expected. But then the script generates more urls with a relative path, and now they become **/tag/link_url**

How can I avoid the "tag/" part in resulting urls? I would really like to avoid using absolute path in the script.

Comment: What do you mean by "the script generates more urls with a relative path" ?

Comment: The script, when called with tag=sometag, will display a list of articles that have this tag. The url for each of them is **href="NNNN.html"**. But when the page is displayed, the links become    **mysite.com/tag/NNNN.html** instead of **mysite.com/NNNN.html**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change all your links to make them absolute. There is a magic tag you have to insert in the `<head>` part of your page, so the browser will know it have to use this address for relative links instead of the current URL in the address bar.

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.mysite.com/" />
</head>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. Not exactly like this but close: 

`$dir = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/';`
`...`
`<base href="<?php echo $dir?>">`

Thank you!